# Ruby 3.0.1 and Rails 6.1.3.2. Active Record has_many and has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

I have a legacy database/tables.  How do I specify the keys for the has_many and has_one relationship?

Parent:
PRN_AUTO_KEY (is the ID field)

Child:
CHL_AUTO_KEY (is the ID field)
PRN_AUTO_KEY (is the foreign key field)

Not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the general One to Many associations.
For example: [Reference](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference).

Have a look at this it's pretty detailed.

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end
```

So, the table structure would be like this:
**Authors**

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | ... |
| 2 | ... | ... |
| 3 | ... | ... |

**Books**

| id | author_id | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ... |
| 2 | 1 | ... |
| 3 | 2 | ... |

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the set_primary_key property of the ActiveRecord object.

Answer (score 0):

For me, as stated, the ID field is not ID.  So I would have to do the following:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :ath_auto_key  
  has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :bks_auto_key    
  belongs_to :author  
end
```